# Pseudo-cleft sentences with the verbs of perception

Tags: infinitives, gerund-vs-infinitive, bare-infinitive, clefts, what-clefts

I know we must use bare infinitives with these verbs in the Active.

e.g. I saw a lady cross the street.

There are other verbs with which we are supposed to use a bare infinitive in the Active.

e.g. I wanted him to leave.
If we transform this sentence into the pseudo-cleft, we see *for*:

What I wanted was **for** him to leave.

My question is can we make pseudo-cleft sentences with the verbs of perception such as *see* or *hear*? Will these sentences contain the non-finite embedded clauses or will those be transformed into the finite ones? In the case they should remain non-finite, shall we use *for* or not?

What I saw was for a lady to cross the street. 
What I saw was a lady cross the street.
What I saw was that a lady crossed the street.

May we use here a gerund?
What I saw was a lady crossing the street.

Comment: If you search on Google for "what I saw was a man", the first page of results includes several instances of 'What I saw was a man' + [_ing_-form] [ ... ] (eg 'What I saw was a man ... standing by the door'), several other constructions, but no examples of ['What I saw was a man' + inf + noun group.] This accords with what I feel is acceptable.

Comment: "What I saw was a lady crossing the street" is definitely grammatical for me, but my first interpretation would be to take "crossing" as a participle: i.e. "What I saw was a lady who was crossing the street." I'm not sure if I would find the sentence grammatical if we stipulate that "crossing" must be interpreted as a gerund.

Comment: A crucial difference between gerund-participial and _to_-infinitivals is that a non-genitive NP can function as subject of the former but not of the latter unless _for_ is present. So "What I saw was a lady crossing the street" is fine but not *"What I saw was a lady cross the street".

Comment: @sumelic _What I saw was a zebra crossing_. Now a deverbal noun, taking a plural form.

Comment: @BillJ I would regard "What I saw was a lady cross the street" as idiomatic, with a slightly different sense to "what I saw was a lady crossing the street". The latter does not indicate that I saw the whole action i.e. of her walking from one pavement to the other - whereas the former does confirm that I saw the whole process.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Plural form?

Comment: @WS2 zebra crossings.

Answer (score 1):

Both bare infinitive and -ing form (leaving aside for a moment the question of whether it is a participle or a gerund) are correct, with a slight difference of meaning/focus (i.e. did you see the whole action, or the activity in progress?)

So: I saw a lady cross the street (whole event, from kerb to kerb)
and: I saw a lady crossing the street (perhaps just one instant of the activity in progress)

When it becomes a pseudo-cleft, only the -ing form is generally acceptable:
What I saw was a lady crossing the street

Comment: I think the premise was that verbs of perception take **bare** (as opposed to marked) infinitives when they do take infinitives; i.e., “I want you _to_ cross the street”, but “I saw you _*to_ cross the street”. I don’t think it was a statement that participle-gerunds can’t be used. Also, the question was really about pseudo-cleft constructions, which you don’t mention at all in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

"What I saw was for a lady to cross the street." makes no sense unless you're trying to sound pseudo-Medieval. "What I saw was a lady cross the street." and "What I saw was that a lady crossed the street." are unnecessarily wordy. I would just write: "I saw a lady cross the street." It's the most natural way anyone would say it unless they get tongue-tied.